# convert money to string format in sql using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am retrieving results from an SQL table using a query in c# and stuck with `format.string` while converting the money. I am unable to convert into string format with zeros. where I want PCN Charge as 7 characters (eg 100 as 0010000) and court fee as ( 15 like 01500).

```
string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
                   " space(1991)," +
                   "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as RecordType" +
                   " , left([Claimant Address7] +'
                   ',29) as ClaimantAddress7 " +
                   ", space(180)," +
```

THE ERROR is HERE

```
"(bat.PCN_Charge) *100 ".ToString().PadLeft(7, '0')  + // value output I get is 10000.0000( where PCN CHARGE is 100)
 ",([Court Fee])*100 ".ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') +  // value I get is 1500
```

( where court fee is 15)

Comment: Why not return the value, and use C# to format the value using `String.Format`?

Comment: Yeah. that is awkward. YOU already are in C#, and SQL is notoriously known for crappy string manipulation - so why not get it as it is (a number) and do the formatting then - in the presentation, as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that, if you are able, you should take advantage of the string formatting in C# to format the string, and just leave the database to return the data. Would this work for you?

If so then you can use:

```
String.Format("{0:0000000}", pcnCharge);
String.Format("{0:00000}", courtFee);
```

I have used the "multiple 0" format here to illustrate exactly what it outputs. There are other number formats you can use, these are referenced on [MSDN: Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), such as `D#` where # is the number of digits you want to show, including leading zeros (for example `D5`)

```
String.Format("{0:D7}", pcnCharge);
String.Format("{0:D5}", courtFee);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.ToString("D7")
```

gives 7 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first - you should not do tiat.

This is a numeric, grab it as this. Store it like this. Format it where you present it to the user. Not in the SQL Query. String manipulation of any form is a weak spot in SQL historically and current and there is no reason to do that in SQL if you pull it anyway into C#.

Now, if you really need to do it, use the SQL erver format funciton which ist there since version 2012 (and you say not which version you use, so I assume you are not using outdated technology).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

This fucntion goes into the .NET framework and uses those format strings, so you can easily do that. It then looks in SQL somehow like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT([pcnCharge],'0000000') .... (I leave the rest to you)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0')
```

Try:

```
.ToString(D7)
```

And instead of:

```
.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')
```

Try:

```
.ToString(D5)
```

`.ToString(D)` Converts to string decimal. `D7` will make sure it is 7 digits so 10000 will be 0010000 I believe it adds zeros to the front. And the same for `D5` except 5 digits.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for ToString formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSSQL 2012, then you can try to use [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)  function for your task.

```
DECLARE @d INT = '10';
SELECT FORMAT ( @d * 100, 'D7', 'en-US' )
```